# Using Grid List and Icon Button in Material UI as separate buttons with onClick action?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to use this grid list from the Material UI framework: https://material-ui.com/components/grid-list/#grid-list-with-titlebars

I am trying to add onClick actions to the GridListTile components and the IconButton components for each of the tiles. I have been able to do so but when I click on the IconButton, this also registers as a click on the GridListTile. Here is a snippet of my current code:

```
<GridList cellHeight={200} className={classes.gridList} cols={Math.round(width/300)} spacing={6}>
    {tileData.map((tile) => (
      <GridListTile key={tile.img} onClick={() => {console1(tile.author)}}>
        <img src={tile.img} alt={tile.title}/>
        <GridListTileBar
          title={tile.title}
          subtitle={<span>by: {tile.author}</span>}
          actionIcon={
            <IconButton aria-label={`info about ${tile.title}`} className={classes.icon} onClick={() => {console2()}}>
              <InfoIcon />
            </IconButton>
          }
        />
      </GridListTile>
    ))}
  </GridList>
```

console1 and console2 are my current functions that activate on click of the GridListTile and IconButton, respectively. Essentially what is happening is that console1 and console2 both activate when I click on the IconButton when only console2 should activate. If someone could help me understand what is happening and adjust my code to address this issue, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the index of the element you are clicking on. Codesandbox with the example you listed above.

Updated Codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-grid-stacking-forked-2b1r4

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import GridList from "@material-ui/core/GridList";
import GridListTile from "@material-ui/core/GridListTile";
import GridListTileBar from "@material-ui/core/GridListTileBar";
import ListSubheader from "@material-ui/core/ListSubheader";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import InfoIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Info";
// import tileData from './tileData';

const tileData = [
  {
    image: "https://via.placeholder.com/150",
    title: "Title 1",
    icon: "Title Icon 1"
  },
  {
    image: "https://via.placeholder.com/150",
    title: "Title 2",
    icon: "Title Icon 2"
  },
  {
    image: "https://via.placeholder.com/150",
    title: "Title 3",
    icon: "Title Icon 3"
  }
];

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    justifyContent: "space-around",
    overflow: "hidden",
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper
  },
  gridList: {
    width: 500,
    height: 450
  },
  icon: {
    color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.54)"
  }
}));

export default function GridComponent() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [title, setTitle] = React.useState("");
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState();

  function handleClick(index, title) {
    console.log("title", title);
    setSelected(index);
    setTitle(title);
  }

  function handleIconClick(index, icon) {
    console.log("icon", icon);
    setSelected(index);
    setTitle(icon);
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <GridList cellHeight={180} className={classes.gridList}>
        <GridListTile key="Subheader" cols={2} style={{ height: "auto" }}>
          <ListSubheader component="div">{title}</ListSubheader>
        </GridListTile>
        {tileData.map((tile, index) => (
          <GridListTile
            className={index === selected ? "selected" : ""}
            key={`${index}${title.title}`}
          >
            <img
              src={tile.image}
              alt={tile.title}
              onClick={() => handleClick(index, tile.title)}
            />
            <GridListTileBar
              title={tile.title}
              subtitle={<span>by: {tile.author}</span>}
              actionIcon={
                <IconButton
                  aria-label={`info about ${tile.title}`}
                  className={classes.icon}
                  onClick={() => handleIconClick(index, tile.icon)}
                >
                  <InfoIcon />
                </IconButton>
              }
            />
          </GridListTile>
        ))}
      </GridList>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does this have a separate onClick function for when the user clicks on the icon button instead of the grid tile though?

Comment: Its wrapped in the container so just pull it out. Updated sanbox

Answer (score 0):

The reason is event bubbling. You can know more about event bubbling: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-event-bubbling-in-javascript

when you click on IconButton the click event bubbles up to the GridListTile.

So both of them console2 and console1 are getting triggered.

You need to use stopPropagation to restrict the event to bubbles up.

Here is

```
console1(e, author) {
 console.log(author);
}

console2(e) {
 e.stopPropagation();
 console.log('console2');
}

<GridList cellHeight={200} className={classes.gridList} cols={Math.round(width/300)} spacing={6}>
    {tileData.map((tile) => (
      <GridListTile key={tile.img} onClick={(e) => {console1(e, tile.author)}}>
        <img src={tile.img} alt={tile.title}/>
        <GridListTileBar
          title={tile.title}
          subtitle={<span>by: {tile.author}</span>}
          actionIcon={
            <IconButton aria-label={`info about ${tile.title}`} className={classes.icon} onClick={(e) => {console2(e)}}>
              <InfoIcon />
            </IconButton>
          }
        />
      </GridListTile>
    ))}
  </GridList>
```

Now

if you click on GridListTile outside IconButton it will call console1

if you click on IconButton, It will only call console2.